# Weird Sanity CMS / Nest.js bug

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

I've been pulling my hair out for a couple hours with this one. But basically I can't render a custom component in the React Portable Text component. I continue to get this error:

> [@portabletext/react] Unknown block type "streaming", specify a
> component for it in the `components.types` prop

Now, I'm 99% I'm correctly passing in this streaming component correctly into components.types props. I then pass the components into the Portable React package from @portabletext/react.

```
const components = {
  types: {
    image: ImageComponent,
    code: Code,
    embed: IframePreview,
    tables: PortableTextTable,
    streaming: StreamingWidget,
  },
  marks: {
    center: props => (
      <div className="text-center">{props.children}</div>
    ),
  }
};
// Set up Portable Text serialization
export const PortableText = props => (
  <PortableTextComponent components={components} {...props} />
);
```

Now there's also clearly some cache issue, as even if I rename 'streaming' to 'streaming123', the terminal still complains about the same block type "streaming".

Has anyone see anything like this with Sanity. Or can they see anything wrong with my code?